# How to programmatically read data stored in OneTouch glucometer?

Tags: embedded

I've had type 1 diabetes for ~11 years (since I was 13). Recently, I've found that some glucometers store blood sugars in memory (in my case, *OneTouch Ultra 2*). The device has a small, rounded input that looks like the one found on any given iPod. Anyway, how can I read the data stored in the glucometers memory? Is the protocol universal? I only ask because whenever I go to the Endocrinologist, the Nurse takes my glucometer and uploads my blood sugars into a database that generates graphs and etc. Should I ask my Endocrinologist? Please, help me! I want to improve the health care management for all type 1 diabetics!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out their [management software](http://www.onetouch.com/software_kit)?

Comment: @blahdiblah, If you make this comment an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some searching reveals that they have dedicated [management software](http://www.onetouch.com/software_kit) that sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Web searches are your friend: http://diabetesdata.pbworks.com/f/OneTouchUltraMiniProtocol.pdf

Comment: +1, even though this is for the onetouch ultra mini. @blahdiblah actually linked me to the better resource.

Comment: What if we are having more then 10 records how to retrieve that? 
02060603CD41020A02050F*0300*031C5802060703FC72 : Here 03 is MSB and 00 is LSB & total number of records are 3, In my case this the response from glucometer , here 0B2C is given. Please suggest hot to get number of records here 02060603CD41020A02050F*0B2C*00031C58020607

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment on why the answer is not useful?